# Couldn't make condition-case work

Tags: error-handling

Hello fellow Emacs Lisp enthusiasts!

I've encountered problem that I am even embarrassed to describe. It is very clear how to use `condition-case` from all the docs and examples that I can find online, but still even the simplest example won't work for me.

Here is a minimal code snippet:

```
(defun foo ()
  (signal 'test-signal '(1 2 3)))

(condition-case nil
    (foo)
  (test-signal nil))
```

I use Emacs 26.1, but encounter the same behaviour on other versions as well.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error symbol `test-signal` is not defined. `C-h f signal` says:

> An error symbol is a symbol with an `error-conditions` property 
>   that is a list of condition names.

Let's check this for some [standard error symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Errors.html) and the `test-signal`

```el
(get 'error 'error-conditions)
;; => (error)

(get 'args-out-of-range 'error-conditions)
;; => (args-out-of-range error)

(get 'test-signal 'error-conditions)
;; => nil
```

To define an error symbol, use `define-error`, e.g.,

```el
(define-error 'test-signal "My error for testing")
```

then you can handle the error in `condition-case`, e.g.,

```el
(condition-case err
    (signal 'test-signal '(1 2 3))
  (test-signal (error-message-string err)))
;; => "My error for testing: 1, 2, 3"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem. I was checkin `eieio` code, but their error (`invalid-slot-type `) doesn't seem to be defined like this.

Comment: @ValeriySavchenko The `invalid-slot-type` error symbol is defined with `define-error` since Emacs 25.1. In early versions, it is defined with `put`. By the way, `define-error` is added in Emacs 24.4.

Comment: Thanks for the information! For now, the package that I'm developing has a minimal supported version of 25.1, so it's not a problem, but it might be if I want to support 24.* versions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a symbol as an error to get Emacs to recognize it:

```el
(define-error 'test-signal
  "Test signal" 'error)

(defun foo ()
  (signal 'test-signal '(1 2 3)))

(condition-case nil
    (foo)
  (error nil))
```

From [`(elisp) Error Symbols`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Symbols.html):

> -- Function: `define-error` `name message &optional parent`
>        In order for a symbol to be an error symbol, it must be defined
>        with `define-error` which takes a parent condition (defaults to
>        `error`).  This parent defines the conditions that this kind of
>        error belongs to.  The transitive set of parents always includes
>        the error symbol itself, and the symbol `error`.  Because quitting
>        is not considered an error, the set of parents of `quit` is just
>        `(quit)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped!